# Unable to join win 7 machines to a domain running Server 2003

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-7

I am fairly new to server administration, but have worked with computers a long time.

I am experienceing a problem I have never had before; I am unable to join any new machines to the domain because I get a DNS error.

I have created a properly named computer object in AD and it is located in the proper OU and group which allows machines to be added to the domain.

At the previous position I held, it was just a matter of creating the machine in AD and then joining it to the domain, with no problems.

However, I think that there is an issue with DNS resolution.

I can provide more detailed information if needed, just didn't know what what is needed to provide assistance.

Comment: Can you ping the domain controller with it's DNS name? What servers do you see if you run 'nslookup domainname' ?

Comment: You don't need to "pre-stage" the computer account in order to join the domain. What DNS server(s) is the client using for DNS?

Comment: you can see the whole log on the client in the netsetup.log which usually is in %SystemRoot%\debug

Comment: Well what I would check is.

1. Does this server have the correct DNS servers configured on it
2. Can the server "Ping domainname" what about "nslookup domainname"
3. unless you have some custom AD permissions you don't need to pre-stage a AD computer account
4. if you are required to pre-stage the account because of AD permissions try to join the domain via command line "netdom join servername /d:domain /ou:OU=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx /ud:domain\userid /pd:* /uo:domain\userid /po:*"
5. make sure you are using the FQDN for all domain commands

Comment: when you all refer to the domain controller, is this the same as the dns server? the server functions as a AD DNS and print server. I'll try the nslookup "domain name" and let you guys know what I find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're Windows 7 systems are at least Professional, Ultimate or Enterprise as they are the versions that can join a domain.

I ran across a hotfix for Windows 7 clients that can't locate the Active Directory Management Gateway service. It might be worth exploring.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969429